# Normal distribution of raw data in multiple regression necessary?

Tags: multiple-regression, histogram

[image]

Here is a distribution of a continuous independent variable I intend to use for multiple regression analysis displayed on a histogram.

I understand that a normal distribution of residuals is a necessary assumption for multiple regression but I was wondering whether the actual data also needs to be transformed so that it too is normal? Is that also an assumption?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No. No distributional assumptions are made on the independent variables, or even the dependent one (unconditionally).

One common distributional assumption that is made in OLS is on the error terms, which are not observable, of course. Even that assumption is not necessary for many puproses such as obtaining the coefficients of regression.

Answer (score 1):

@Aksakal is entirely correct, you do not require the dependent variable to be normally distributed. In **some** cases, your histogram may tell you that a different functional form are required for your data - for example, say your dependent variable is healthcare spending. You are likely to have a lot of low values, and a small number of very high ones (i.e. right skewed data). You could see people doing things like regressing on the log of healthcare spending, or applying a generalized linear model with a log link (that does the transformation for you - simplifying here!) and some funky distribution (e.g. a gamma distribution). Those are more advanced applications, and if you stick with statistics, you'll probably want to learn some of those models. They aren't too much of a stretch once you know OLS.

That said, by the looks of it, those data are probably going to be fine in OLS.

Comment: Understood, thanks. But when looking at residuals of a variable against the regression line, if the residuals dont show homoscedasticity, at that point I would hav eto turn to transformations such as the log to correct the issue?

Comment: It depends on what you are using the model for. There are valid applications of regression for which the heteroskedacity of the residuals is irrelevent.